# How to avoid curl to try to connect with a https site using SSLv3 by default

Tags: curl, centos5

I need to connect from my CentOS 5 machine to sites over a https connection.

The problem is that by using curl, by default, it tries to connect using SSLv3 which is not supported in the server, so, the connection fails.

How can I disable completely the support for SSLv3 in client? the fact is that I cannot try to override the configuration by using some command line switch because I have some binaries that use curl functionality inside.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this switch to change the version --sslv2
check out curl documentation 
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: As I told, I don't have to use a switch, because I have some binaries where curl functionality is also used. Of course, I don't have access to change those binaries. I have compared curl configuration to some server that has curl 7.19.7. In that server it works https connection. My local server has curl 7.29.0 and curl tries to use SSLv3 by default, so I am sure there is something wrong with some sort of configuration.